# How to use RSA?

Tags: python, encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption, private-key

I trying to use RSA to encrypt my data in Python.

I created two small (private and public) keys

```
e : 14918179  N : 15372757
D : 7495819   N : 15372757
```

I tried to encrypt a small value (10) with those keys, and it worked. But the problem is that it takes a long time to do.
For example, I compared it to openssl by using a big key and long string and it worked under a second.
And I know there is a third library for using RSA (not a big fan of them).
I am trying to use this method to encrypt my data that is going to be sent to the server and it should do it under a second
How can I do it?

Comment: do not use RSA to encrypt data (that is not only slow it is also bad for security reasons [unless you also use optimal padding...]); use RSA to encrypt a session key and encrypt the data symmetrically (i.e. with AES-GCM) using that session key.

Comment: While I am surely an advocate of doing things from scratch to understand the principles, I do not advice you to reinvent the wheel. Use a library if you want to encrypt data, or even better use already existing security protocols ( HTTPS, SSL, TLS) and use a library to access them.

Comment: Without seeing your code, we can't really tell why it's slow. But as a random guess, are you using the 3-argument form of [`pow()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)? If not, you should be. Also note that a simple Python script using Python's generic integer math will never be as fast as a C library specifically optimized for RSA. But with that change (and reasonable algorithms) it should at least get close to the same ballpark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in general your questions on performance are answered here. [wikipedia : modular exponentiation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation)

The article describes

- Direct exponentiation
- Memory efficient exponentiation
- Binary exponentiation

### Direct Exponentiation

raise to the power e and take the modulo.
This is straight forward, but the size of the number pre modulo is extermely large.

### Memory efficient exponentiation

Replacing the power operation with a multiply e times, allows the accumulated result to always be within the modulo range.  This limits the size of the `bignum` and speeds up the operation.

### Binary exponentiation

If you convert the power to a binary number

if e = 13  => 1101
pow(n, 13) = pow( n, 8) * pow(n,4) * pow(n, 1)
So for an m bit exponent, then only about m operations need to be done.

Combining the memory efficient and binary exponentiation solves most of the performance.

Python offers an implementation of these improvements using the 3 argument power function e.g.

```
>>> import timeit
>>> t = timeit.Timer( 'print(pow( 10,14918179, 15372757))' )
>>> t.timeit(1)
10140931
0.06365180000000237

>>> u = timeit.Timer( 'print(pow( 10,14918179) % 15372757)' )
>>> u.timeit(1)
10140931
15.021656000000007
```

The 3 parameter of `pow` takes .06s whilst the 2 parameter version of `pow` takes 15 seconds.